# How to remove adminbar in Wordpress on certain pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to remove the toolbar/adminbar on my main page when users are logged in but it doesn't work properly. Actually it doesn't work.

I found this code :

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_website_remove_admin_bar' );
function my_website_remove_admin_bar() {

   // hide the admin bar on your main page
   if ( is_home() )
      show_admin_bar( false );


}
```

I try to have it out of my homepage...

Comment: How about `is_front_page()`?

Comment: This solution doesn't work but thank you for commenting ! However "rnevius" found the solution !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`show_admin_bar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/show_admin_bar) filter would be much more appropriate in this case:

```
function conditional_hide_admin_bar() {
    return is_front_page() ? false : true;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'conditional_hide_admin_bar' );
```

Comment: we might even simplify it to `return ! is_front_page();`